# Parsing Error Response in Camel

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

New to Camel, and I'm trying to parse a response error xml.  Within the camel-context I need to determine if a specific value exists in the error file, and handle it differently than other errors.

The other errors use a series of when statements:

```
<when>
    <xpath>/abc:ErrorResponse/abc:Error/abc:Message/.</xpath>
    <setHeader headerName="RESPONSE_STRING">
        <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">/abc:ErrorResponse/abc:Error/abc:Message/.</xpath>
    </setHeader>

    <setHeader headerName="MY_DATA_FIELD"><constant>Error</constant></setHeader>
    <to uri="def:doErrorStuff" pattern="InOnly"/>
</when>
<when>
    <xpath>/ghi:ErrorResponse/ghi:Error/ghi:Message/.</xpath>
        <setHeader headerName="RESPONSE_STRING">
            <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">/ghi:ErrorResponse/ghi:Error/ghi:Message/.</xpath>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="MY_DATA_FIELD"><constant>Error</constant></setHeader>
        <to uri="def:doErrorStuff" pattern="InOnly"/>
</when>
```

My error XML file has an outer error element with child "Code" element.  I need to parse the value of the code element
UPDATE: HERE IS THE XML I AM PARSING

```
 <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://myhost/location1/">
    <Error>
        <Type>reserved</Type>
        <Code>TEXT_I_NEED_TO_PARSE_IN_WHEN_STATEMENT</Code>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>some_id</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

I used a combination of xpath and 'simple' to make the check. Like this:

```
    <when>
        <xpath>/ghi:ErrorResponse/ghi:Error/ghi:Message/.</xpath>
        <when>
            <simple>${in.body.code} == 'StringIAmSearchingFor'</simple>
            <!-- Do Stuff --!>
        </when>
    </when>
```

However, I am not getting the response I expect.
1. Is there something wrong with this approach or the syntax?
2. Is there a way to combine the double when layout so they are and-ed together.  Otherwise, if I add my "when" statement just ahead of the existing two, the existing "ghi" when statement will never get executed (the xpath statements match).

Comment: Please post some example input.

Comment: @Jens - no problem, posted the xml

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using xpath on your input suggesting that it's XML, then simple (${in.body.code}) which in that case also would be XML. Simple is used to traverse java bodies and not other formats such as XML. Stick to XPATH all the way - your code above can easily be implemented in xpath. Another way, of course, would be to unmarshal the XML into java objects using [xstream](http://camel.apache.org/xstream) or [jaxb](http://camel.apache.org/jaxb), then you can use only simple/OGNL/groovy or whatnot.
2. Since I recommend you to solve this very case with xpath alone, you can of course use the xpath and operator to and several xpath expressions together. All logic and power in camel choice/when reside in the expression language you are using (be it simple or xpath), so if you want to mix expression languages, you have to build up sort of a [decision tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree). That could actually be something good if you are trying to implement very complex routing logic. For a single special case - it's, IMHO, just messy.

Comment: Thanks for the great response.  I will try using a single xpath down to the "Code" element's value and compare that to the string I am looking for.  Not sure how that will look, but I'll play around with it.